# ListView Scrollbar is not resizing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, listview

I went through different solutions from stackoverflow and web, but didn't work. the scrollbar of listView is very tiny, I want it to be large enough. I used `android:scrollbarSize="55dip"` but it didn't work, android ignores it.

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/azadRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="آزاد"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qafiaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="قافیہ"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sabiqaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="سابقہ"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="Finder"
        android:text="Finder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="359dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
        android:scrollbarSize="55dip"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**custom.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:scrollbarSize="55dip"

        android:textSize="20px" android:paddingTop="10dip" android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line too with the scrollsize you used:

```
 android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
```